# Iterative conception: Boolos and Von Neumann universe

Tags: set-theory, philosophy

I am reading Boolos' famous article "The iterative conception of set" from Benacerraff and Putnam's collection of papers "Philosophy of Mathematics".

At page 493 (2nd edition) Boolos says that: "$\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ are both pure sets and are formed at stages 1 and 2, repectively".

What sounds weird to me is that in the Von Neumann Universe (henceforth $V$) the set $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is formed at stage 3. I think I am missing the reason for this difference and hence I don't know if it has relevant consequences.

What strikes me in particular is that a nice characteristic of $V$ is that every ordinal has a rank equal to itself. That is, obviously, if we stick to Von Neumann definition of ordinal number.

But, using Boolos' stage theory (assuming it is something intelligibly distinguishable from $V$, of which I am not sure and hence this question) and Zermelo's definition of ordinal ($0=\emptyset, 1=\{\emptyset\}, 2=\{\{\emptyset\}\}, 3=\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, and so on) it would seem that Boolos could keep this nice feature while changing the overall structure.

So, in no particular order whatsoever: is there a difference between $V$ and Boolos' stage theory? If yes, what determines it and what are the consequences? Is the thing about the ordinal being equal to its rank relevant in any way?

Comment: So Boolos uses a slightly different indexing of the stages than von Neumann does.  Who cares?

Comment: I was supposing he did, but reading carefully he uses Von Neumann indexing in deriving the axiom of infinity from his stage theory. My main doubt is about the process of stage formation: is it different and, if yes, how? The indexing was more of a curiosity and, as you noted, an immaterial one. I'm sorry if the question is dumb, I'm just new to the subject.

Comment: IMO there is a difference; see Boolos, [Iteration Again](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43154050). While in [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) we have that $V_1= \{ \emptyset \}$ (i.e. the power.set of the empty set) in Boolos Stage 1 we have two elements: $\emptyset$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$, i.e. "all possible collections of sets formed at stage $0$".

Comment: There is a detailed book dedicated to "concepts" of set: Luca Incurvati, [Conception of Set and the Foundations of Mathematics (2020, Cambridge University Press)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Conceptions_of_Set_and_the_Foundations_o/5InPDwAAQBAJ)